# Python multiprocessing "can't pickle" when using logging

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-logging

I'm using multiprocessing.Pool to parallelize some Python code I wrote for simulation (of combat in D&D 5e). However, I'm getting this error: `can't pickle _thread.RLock objects`. I did some research and it looks like the problem is that my simulation uses objects that have loggers (from the `logging` module). I would still like to support logging for single-process runs of the simulation (so people can do debugging/check output), but logging support for multiple-process runs is less important to me, because once the user knows the simulation works correctly they don't generally need a play-by-play. How can I refactor my code so that logging is not an issue here (disabling logging when there are multiple processes, implementing logging in a way that multiprocessing accepts, or something else)?

Some code from my Simulation class:

```
    def process_run(self, num):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        """
        The method given to an individual process to do work. Run only once per process so we don't need to reset anything

        :param num: which iteration of the loop am I
        :return:
        """
        self._encounter.run()
        return self._encounter.get_stats()

    def mp_run(self, n=1000, p=None):
        """
        Run the Encounter n times (using multiprocessing), then print the results
        :param n: number of times to run the encounter
        :param p: number of processes to use. If None, use max number of processes
        :return: aggregate stats
        """
        if p:
            pool = Pool(p)  # use user-specified number of processes
        else:
            pool = Pool()  # use max number of processes as user didn't specify
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(self.process_run, range(n)):
            self.update_stats(result)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        self.calculate_aggregate_stats(n)
        self.print_aggregate_stats()
        return self._aggregate_stats
```

Some code that uses logging (from the Encounter class, which each Simulation has an instance of):

```
            self.get_logger().info("Round %d", self.get_round())
            unconscious = [comb.get_name() for comb in self.get_combatants() if comb.has_condition("unconscious")]
            if unconscious:
                self.get_logger().info("Unconscious: %s", str(unconscious))
            dead = [comb.get_name() for comb in self.get_combatants() if comb.has_condition("dead")]
            if dead:
                self.get_logger().info("Dead: %s", str(dead))
```

If you need more code examples, let me know.